# Upload a photo via Graph API using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, facebook-graph-api, upload, jersey

I have a Java application and i try to upload a photo to Facebook via graph api with Jersey.
Until now everything works fine with Jersey I can publish messages etc.

I searched hours to find an example how to do it.
The best tutorial I found was this one:

http://neopatel.blogspot.de/2011/04/jersey-posting-multipart-data.html

The only thing I know is that I have to use multipart/formdata.

Does anyone have an example or know have to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the [jersey-multipart](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/contribs/jersey-multipart/index.html) package?

You create a `FormDataMultiPart` with a `FileDataBodyPart` for the file and a `FormDataBodyPart` for the message and access_token..

Comment: Thanks Pete you gave me a good hint. Now it works. I will post my solution later.

Answer (score 2):

This is my Solution.

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";
File file = new File("path");

ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
Client client = Client.create(cc);

WebResource webResource = client.resource(url); 
FormDataMultiPart fdmp = new FormDataMultiPart(); 

fdmp.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("source", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
fdmp.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("message", "YAY I did it!"));
fdmp.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("access_token", accessToken));

ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, fdmp); 
String string = response.getEntity(String.class);
```